# Replace EF Core Default Schema in xUnit

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, integration-testing, ef-database-first

I would like to perform integration testing on my API which connects to an oracle database via EF Core (database-first). Initially, I went with `Testcontainers.Oracle` but it was running too slow on my machine. Hence, I decided to perform the test using a separate schema. I do not wish to use in-memory database to perform my integration tests.

I have two schemas:

1. `Schema1` (the original schema which the context was scaffolded from)
2. `Schema2` (I would like to create the tables in schema1 here and run my tests)

How do I override the default schema in my web application factory? Currently I have tried to check whether unit test is running in my source project but I would prefer do it inside the test project in case it is overwritten by a new scaffold.

```cs
public class MyApiFactory : WebApplicationFactory<IApiMarker>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(optionsBuilder =>
                optionsBuilder.UseOracle(""));

            // is it possible to change default schema of the model builder?
        });
    }
}

public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyTable> MyTable{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Schema1");

#if DEBUG
        if (UnitTestDetector.IsRunningFromXUnit)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Schema2");
        }
#endif

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable1>(entity =>
        {
            // some table configuration
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why not just run with actual oracle instance and rollback the transactions once the tests completed?

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang You are not wrong, that would work but I would personally prefer if there is a clear separation, similar like how we would spin up docker containers and dispose them at the end of the tests.

Comment: Change the current schema after connection instead, with `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=schema_other;`. What you ask isn't clean to begin with - you're trying to use a schema, a logical namespace in the database, as if it was a different database. That's not its job though, which is why the schema is part of the *model*, not the configuration. I understand why you want to do that: in Oracle a database is equivalent to a different server instance, with different binaries and files. An Oracle schema is closer to a SQL Server database though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the explanation! I should look into setting up another instance for testing